# popover, clicking out and hiding

Tags: jquery

Basically, when I click outside the popover, I want it to hide it. For me to remove the popover, I'd have to click on the div to remove it.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        var content = $(this).data('content-target');
        try { content = $(content).html() } catch(e) {/* Ignore */}
        return content || $(this).data('content');
    }
});
```

I tried adding:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
        $('#popover').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work.. my current popover is as listed:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-title="Popover Title" data-content="<?php echo stripslashes($row['details']); ?>
```

Comment: I think problem lies with your condition `$('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0`. Can you please try `($(e.target).is('.popover') || $(e.target).parents('.popover').length > 0))`

Comment: @eithedog i tried that, and nothing happened.. I tried clicking out of the box, and it didn't close.

Comment: Ups - sorry, this actually hides the popover when you click on `.popover` or anything inside it. Can you please add ! before entire thing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap for this? If yes, you can grab the the latest version and simply do this:

```
$('.popover').popover({
    trigger: 'focus'
})
```

See "Dismissable Popover" on the [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Answer (score 0):

Please find attached the fiddle with the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nysHH/

1. I think the problem additionally lies with the block `$('#popover').popover('hide');` - I've replaced it with `[data-toggle="popover"]` selector as this is the element that spawns the popover.
2. Additionally, if adding the event of hiding the popover on document click, as soon as you click on the `[data-toggle="popover"]`, the event will fire and popover will not appear at all. The solution is either check if popover is visible, or (which I've used) checking if the target you're clicking on isn't the `[data-toggle="popover"]`